# Multi label classification and sigmoid function

Tags: keras, convolutional-neural-network

I'm new to neural networks so this may be silly question.
I have build standard CNN network for image classification. I want multi-label classification network so I 
use binary_crossentropy as loss function:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

and have sigmoid function as activation function in last layer (two neurons for two labels):

```
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Output gives me something like this:

```
[[0.000497834], [0.99942183]]
```

1. Why does this two numbers add to 1, isn't sigmoid output suppose to be independent?
2. What should I do to get independent probability as output (for example, if image doesn't belong to any of two classes
   output should be close to 0 for two neurons, something like this : [[0.001], [0.001]]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 0.000497834 + 0.99942183 =  0.999919664 (not 1)

Comment: Can you post complete model definition? You expectation with 2 sigmoid outputs is correct (outs should be independent)

Comment: Also, post few rows from train_y . If most rows are not multi-babel, network might learn to predict only 1 output as 1 and another as 0

Comment: You are using binary cross entropy, so it's giving you 2 outputs as you also have 2 o/p at sigmoid, something is wrong with your arch maybe.. as to what you desire and what you are actually doing.. To get. The third class, that isn't easy because the o/p will then be close to .5 for both the classes to indicate that model isn't sure about this...

Comment: Shamit Verma you were right, most rows in train_y are not multi-label, thanks. What about second question? @Aditya Is this good approach to the problem if i want my output to be like [0.01, 0.01] when image doesn't belong to any class?

Comment: No you won't get lower predictions at least the scale at which you want because the sum will always add to ~1; Also looking at your sharing it doesn't look like multi label to me rather multi class, both have different meaning

Comment: Ok @Aditya but using softmax and categorical_crossentropy for multi class would give me output that sums up to 1 so still not what i want.

Comment: @Kamil, what is the ground truth you were expecting for that particular example? Can you share some of the data and then some of the outputs vs targets?

Comment: Exactly as JahKnows said, add your data sample else we can't help you.

Comment: @JahKnows hi, my goal was to build a CNN that would recognize if image is dog or cat but i would also want that if I give for example image of the house as input my network will output something like [[0.001], [0.001]] indicating that its neither of these two (or at least some output that would help me indicate that input image was neither dog nor cat)